# Voltage controlled connection of two signals that are at higher voltage than the control voltage

Tags: transistors, mosfet, digital-logic, switching, logic-level

Given are two signals A and B. I want to control the connection between them by a signal C. However, signal C is a logic signal with a voltage of 3.3V for high and 0V for low whereas signals A and B are at a level of 4V.

How can this be done? Using a Mosfet with C as gate and A and B as Drain or source, respectively will not work as C would have a lower voltage than the source. Therefore, the difference G - S would always be negative.

Comment: What is the impedance of these signals and can some current (even a tiny current) be drawn from them? Are they always 4V or varying? AC or DC? Frequency? What is the desired resistance of the switch? Switching time/frequency?

Comment: What do you mean by "control the connection between them"?

Comment: @peufeu: Yes, some current can be drawn from them. They're varying around 4V DC. A is a battery and B the charging voltage. So, resistance should be as low as possible. Switching time/frequency should be less than 1 second.

Comment: @Justin: I mean that A and B are connected when C is high and disconnected when C is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to think of.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, but where does that 5V come from? I'd suggest ORing Sig_A and Sig_B to the net which now is called +5V.

Comment: Huisman - Hermetica gave very little information about the rest of the circuit.  If there  is a signal there is a source of power for the signal and 5V is very common.  If more information is given then a better solution can be provided.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. In my circuit, A is a battery and B the charging voltage. I want to be able to cutoff the charging by signal C.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming signal C originates from at least a 3.3V power supply, you could use a **relay that accepts a 3V3 coil voltage** and drive that relay indirectly with signal C.

Example: [JQC-3F-03VDC](https://voron.ua/files/pdf/relay/JQC-3F(T73).pdf)

Another solution could be using a (mosfet) **solid-state relay**, but check the maximum load current does not exceed the specs. Maybe signal C can drive the LED directly (i.e. with a resistor in series).

Example: [VO1400AEF](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84724/vo1400aeftr.pdf)